# Guardar valor de option value en localstorage

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Estimados estoy ultilizando React, nesecito guardar el valor seleccionado del value del option select (si selecciona value=1, o selecciona value=2, guardar el valor seleccionado en el localstorage para obtener el valor y utlilizatlo en otra pagina, dejo lo que tengo.)

```js
let users = [
    { value: "1", label: "Usuario 1" },
    { value: "2", label: "Usuario 2" },
  ];

  users.unshift({
    value: "",
    label: "[ Seleccione una opicón ]",
  });
```

```html
<select
              className="form-select"
              name="options"
              onChange={handleInputChange}
              value={options}
              onBlur={() => seterrorSelect("")}
            >
              {users.map((item) => {
                return (
                  <option key={item.value} value={item.value}>
                    {item.label}
                  </option>
                );
              })}
            </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Cuando captures el valor en tu función del evento on change llamas con la palabra reservada **localStorage** asi y puedes setear cualquier valor

```
const handleInputChange=()=>e=>
{
 let val=e.target.value;
localStorage.setItem("item_id", `${val}`);
}
```

y asi basicamente puedes guardar datos,para obtenerlos solo accedes a la función **getItem**

```
 let item = localStorage.getItem("item_id");
```

Aquí codigo completo

```
import React from "react";
let users = [
  { value: "1", label: "Usuario 1" },
  { value: "2", label: "Usuario 2" }
];

users.unshift({
  value: "",
  label: "[ Seleccione una opicón ]"
});
const handleInputChange = () => (e) => {
  let val = e.target.value;
  localStorage.setItem("item_id", `${val}`);
};
const General = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <select
        className="form-select"
        name="options"
        onChange={handleInputChange()}
      >
        {users.map((item) => {
          return (
            <option key={item.value} value={item.value}>
              {item.label}
            </option>
          );
        })}
      </select>
    </div>
  );
};
export default General;
```

Comment: Gracias, nop me queda claro, como implemetarlo, podrias ser un poco mas explicativo, Gracias

Comment: tienes una función llamada handleInputChange al cambiar de valor el select,ahi te estoy poniendo esa función y te estoy guardando el valor en el storage

Comment: es una constante para controlar los inputs, no la puede colocar de nuevo por que me dice que la redeclaro, podrias implementarlo en el ejemplo que deje dentro del select

Comment: Te comparti el codigo completo funcionando,el valor que seleccionas se guarda en storage

Comment: Gracias ya funciona, si no es molestia como hago una validacion si esta vacio el value,